# CocoaPods installing Parse Ruby version error

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods, parse-server

I am trying to install Parse on a new project using Cocoapods. I get the error ruby-2.3 is not installed, but I have installed 2.3.0. gem.

```
Mac:xx richard$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Bolts (1.9.0)
Installing Parse (1.17.2)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
ruby ParseUI/Scripts/convert_images.rb         ParseUI/Resources/Images/         ParseUI/Generated/PFResources

rbenv: version `ruby-2.3' is not installed (set by /Users/richard/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Parse/1.17.2-3b31a/.ruby-version)
```

Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In terminal update rbenv before pod install in project file. This cleared the error.

```
Mac:~ user$ rbenv install -l 
Mac:~ user$ rbenv install 2.3.8
Mac:~ user$ gem install bundler

then switch to project file
Mac:Project user$ pod install
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always explain what the code does and how it helps.